# How can I update kernel source to newer one without losing added code?

Tags: android, git, diff

I have a snapshot of the android kernel source code from a while ago, to which I have added some features.
Now I have a newer version of the source published by manufacturer. How can I update my source without losing my changes?
If i use

```
diff -Naur old/ new/ > new1.patch
```

"" then apply patch by

```
patch -p1 < new1.patch
```

I will lose modified code and extra files that were available in old source
but if I use

```
diff -Naur new/ old/ > new2.patch
```

It preserves my modified code and extra files, but I don't know if the source is updated or not. Is there any solution for this? Perhaps using git rebase or merge? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand correctly: you had a kernel version provided by your manufacturer, to which you made your own modifications?

Then you want to upgrade your kernel version, but still have your modification?

The most natural way is to work with branches and merges. For example, you could update your branch `master` according to the deliveries from your manufacturer, and maintain a branch `my_code_branch` (of course, you need a much better branch name than this) to which you merge upstream kernel updates.

```
a---b---c---d - master (from manufacturer)
             \
              +---x - my_branch (your own changes)
```

Then when an upgrade comes from your manufacturer, you update your master with:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin master # or whatever your remote is called
```

and get:

```
a---b---c---d---e - master (from manufacturer)
             \
              +---x - my_branch (your own changes)
```

Then merge the changes from your manufacturer, into your own branch:

```
$ git checkout my_branch
$ git merge master
```

to get:

```
a---b---c---d---e---+ - master
             \       \
              +---x---y - my_branch
```

---

If you don't need the local `master` branch, you could also stay on `my_branch` and pull directly:

```
$ git pull origin master   # while on my_branch
```

---

Note that you could also do the opposite: your code in `master` while maintaining a branch `manufacturer` that you'd keep up-to-date with the manufacturer.

Comment: Thank you very much.i don't need local master branch,so i used pull origin master.but this structure added to all my files <<<< HEAD my_codes ======= >>>>>>>>> c9dfs93rr... !! how can i avoid that ? also in some files put original code line after my modified code line !! This is a liitle part of log after running pull ... Auto-merging sound/soc/msm/qdsp6v2/q6adm.c
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in sound/soc/msm/qdsp6v2/q6adm.c

Comment: This is a conflict. Something happened at this location in both branches that you are merging together, and `git` does not know if you want the changes from `my_codes`, or those from `c9dfs93` (probably `origin/master`), or a combination of both. You need to solve these conflicts by hand: open the files that conflict (here `sound/soc/msm/qdsp6v2/q6adm.c`) and search for <<<<. Then either delete one side of the ====, or pick the rows that will make your final version. Test to build, then `git add` the file, and `git commit`. You'll get a default merge commit text, which mentions conflicts.

Comment: oh thanks saved me lots of headaches,what about rebase -i ? is this different for my situation ?

Comment: Rebasing is rewriting history, which can lead to complications. The best you can do here is to merge. Suppose that you have used `x`, you don't want to modify it, you want to be able to refer to it as it was at the time. If you rebased `my_branch` on top of master (`e`) instead of `d`, your commit `x` would not be as it was when you used it. Rebasing records the branch backwards, and replays the changes on top of another commit. Let the history show what actually happened: you had a branch based on `master`, you updated `master`, you want to update your branch while keeping its history.